# Calling a same javascript function on different php element generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a user control, now 1 page can have 2 user controls, The php method that generates control is

```
public function GenerateControl($control_name)
{ 
  echo "<input type='text' id='".$control_name."' name='".$control_name."' value='' size='80' readonly/>&nbsp;";
  echo "<button width='20' height='20' onclick='ShowClientList()' style='padding: 0;'>...</button>";



  echo "<div id='client_select_popup' class='popup'  style='display:none;'>
    <div id='client-grid' align='center'></div>



    &nbsp;<input style='width:60px;width:60px;margin-top: 4px;' type='submit' value='Select' onclick='ChooseClient(\"$control_name\")'  />
    <input style='width:60px;width:60px;margin-top: 4px;' type='submit' value='Cancel' onclick='CancelChooseClient()'  />
</div>";
}
```

Now when I call ChooseClient function and try to set the value, it always gets only the first control and doesn't get the second one.

```
function ChooseClient( edit_client)
 {

var sm      = clientGrid.getSelectionModel(),
    row_arr = sm.getSelection(),
    row_obj, id, name;

var clienttype = $('#clienttype').val();
if( clienttype == 1)
{

if ( row_arr[0] )
    {
    row_obj = row_arr[0],
    id      = row_obj.get( 'affiliate_id' ),
    name    = id + ' - ' + row_obj.get( 'affiliate_name' );

    $('#'+edit_client).val(name);
    }
    else
    {
    alert( 'Select Affiliate at first' );
    }
 }
```

so  $('#'+edit_client).val(name); always sets in the first control and doesn't set on the second one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `$control_name` unique for each control?

Comment: can you try providing a demo of your issue using sites like codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Xlander - yes $control_name is unique for each control